# ADB Issues for Ubuntu 22.04 (Only 2023 solutions please.)

Tags: 22.04, adb

So, when I boot my android device (normally) and type adb devices it show up. But if I adb reboot bootloader and try adb devices again nothing shows. Everything I've tried leads me right back to this same spot. Can someone help me out?
Even the tiniest bit is appreciated

Answer: using a snapdragon CPU I have zero access to a bootloader. Sorry for any confusion and feel free to ignore this.

Comment: what are you trying to do? You also might want to check out our [Android site](https://android.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. `adb reboot bootloader` [reboots your phone into fastboot mode](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/running#flashing-a-device), and adb [does not work](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/adb-commands-not-working-in-fastboot-mode-is-it-normal.3020532/) on devices that are in fastboot mode, unless you have installed a custom recovery. You can use the `fastboot` tool to communicate with your device while it is in fastboot mode.

Comment: Yes, I have the fasboot tools. But it still doesn't work. This is for an older tablet if it helps as my phone doesn't allow access to it at all? (It's a snapdragon instead of exynos)

Comment: *what* doesn't work? `adb` **will not work** on devices in fastboot mode. If you go to our [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com) site and describe in detail what you are trying to do, perhaps the people there will be able to help you accomplish your goal.